# For what is the Pinia mapStores function exactly

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

What is the reason to use [mapStores()](https://pinia.vuejs.org/api/modules/pinia.html#mapStores) when using pinia with the options api. I can achieve the exact same behavior when setting it as data value:

```
<template>
   <pre>name: {{ myStore.name }}</pre>
</template>

<script>
import { useMyStore } from '@stores/myStore.js';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            myStore: useMyStore(),
        };
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can't accidentally reassign myStore with mapStores. Otherwise I'd expect it to work the same way